# How to get instagram user ID/access tocken from iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, instagram

In my iPhone app,there is a switch for sharing the photos to users instagram profile.
How to get the instagram id in my app.

(i am not sharing the posts directly from the app,i woud like to send the particulars to server,from there sharing happens-)

I have registered my app in Instagram and got  CLIENT ID,Client secret

Comment: Are you storing the access token for the Instagram account somewhere?

Comment: no i have created the app in instagram and got CLIENT ID and CLIENT SECRET only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use those ID and SECRET to authenticate with Instagram to get the access tokens for your users to make requests to the API, check [here](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) to see how you can initiate the authentication flow and then find a solution that fits what you're trying to do.

Comment: hey...how can we find our instaram user ID and followers list from iphone app

Comment: That's separate question from the current one, and can also be resolved just by probably reading the API. If you want that answered I suggest opening a new question, and resolving this one first.

Comment: thanks...i have posted my new question here--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833972/how-can-we-find-our-instaram-user-id-and-followers-list-and-ther-user-id-from-ip

Comment: if your CLIENT ID is fe35465454654654654654 and your USER ID is 458987,You will ge access token as 458987.fe35465.65465sg54654sfa48