# How can we find our instaram user ID and followers list and ther user ID from iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, instagram

I have an i phone app,on a button click how can I take our Instagram UserID ?

Currently I am using instagram SDK and i am getting my followers' ID, But not getting an idea how to find my USER ID

[This](https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk) is the code i am using now to find followers USER ID

Comment: @David Brunow Brunow ..now link works

Comment: How can we get Profile information like username and user email id..can any one resolve this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is being fixed,follow the above link
You will get access token with your user id and clint id in a format as below

userid.client_ID.accesstocken

if  your CLIENT ID is fe35465454654654654654 and your USER ID is 458987,You will ge access token as 458987.fe35465.65465sg54654sfa48